# Spring Controller: Handling Custom return types

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'd like my Spring Controllers to return an `Either<Redirect, X>` which I can then unwrap using a Filter/AOP to avoid repetitive "is this a redirect, or is it a 2xx response" code.

- If the return type is an `Either.Left(Redirect("host", "port"))` then my Filter/AOP will return a 302.
- If the return type is an `Either.Right(Vehicle(...))` then my Filter/AOP will return a 200 and serialize the payload to JSON.

e.g.

```
@GetMapping("vehicles/{id}")
public Either<Redirect, Vehicle> getById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return someService.get(id);
}
```

Is it possible to do this using Spring? Or do I have to handle this redirection in my Controller layer e.g.

```
@GetMapping("vehicles/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return someService.get(id)
                      .fold(
                          redirect -> ResponseEntity.status(302).location(...).build(),
                          payload -> ResponseEntity.ok(payload).build()
                      );
}
```

---

A bit of extra context if it is useful:

This app is a member of a cluster and has a "local state". The total state is spread across the cluster. 
As a result, when a request comes in for a particular id/key it could be coming into the wrong instance of the app, and will need to be redirected to the correct instance.